# Referencing a List of Variables in Do Loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, extract, p-value

I have created a series of multimodal distributions to test the effectiveness of the Hartigan dip test for unimodality. These distributions each have 2000 observations and created using one or more rnorm function.

The purpose of this code is outlined below.

1. Calculate the dip statistic for each distribution to be stored in the "statistic" variable
2. Extract the p-value into the "dipstatistic" variable and store them for later use
3. Reference this variable after every distribution has undergone this calculation to be assessed at a later date

I believe that the problem I have here is in indicating the variables that are generated outside of the loop. Does anyone have any advice of how to rectify this probelm?

```
x1 <- rnorm(2000,4,.5)

x2 <- c(rnorm(1000,0,1),rnorm(1000,4,1)) 

x3 <- c(rnorm(667,0,1),rnorm(667,4,1),rnorm(666,8,1))

x4 <- c(rnorm(500,0,1),rnorm(500,4,1),rnorm(500,8,1),rnorm(500,12,1))

dip.test(x1, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
dip.test(x2, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
dip.test(x3, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
dip.test(x4, simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)

y=4

dipstatistic <- rep(0,y)

ID <- 1:y
for (i in 1:y) {
  statistic <- dip.test("need to find way to identify variables" , simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
  dipstatistic[i] <- statistic$p.value
}

dipstatistic
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use an sapply here if you join all your variables in a list.

```
dipstatistic <- sapply(list(x1,x2,x3,x4), function(x) {
    dip.test(x , simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)$p.value
})
```

Comment: what if I were applying this to a list of n distributions. I'm using this to test hundreds of distributions simultaneously so is there a way i can make this correspond to a list x1:xn

Comment: Do you really have 100 separate variables? If so, you may want to rethink how you are creating those and put them in a list directly. Otherwise you could use `paste()` and `get()` but it sounds like they should be in a list in the first place.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about how to use this functionatlity which is why I had planned to use a loop with the distribution name changing on each loop to correspond to a new distribution. With my current estimate there are 800 distinct distributions being tested in this way. 

I will look up the way to use those commands for my use.